# How to check if id is in array mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have one endpoint in my API REST that would check if the object of ids that i receive from `req.body` (`{users: ['id1','id2']}`) is in my db.

I have this:

```
router.post(
  '/checkchat',
  isLoggedIn(),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const { users } = req.body;
    const chats = await Chat.find({
      $and: [
        {
          users: {
            $elemMatch: { $eq: users[0] }
          }
        },
        {
          users: {
            $elemMatch: { $eq: users[1] }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    if (chats.length > 0) {
      res.status(205).json(chats);
    } else {
      const chat = await Chat.create({
        users: users.users,
        messages: []
      });
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(users[0], { $push: { chats: chat } });
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(users[1], { $push: { chats: chat } });
      res.status(200).json(chat);
    }
  }
);
```

I found in mongoose documentation `$elemMatch` but it doesn't work. Always find 0 items in await Chat.find... that's mean the condition ($and: ...) isn't work

i need check if the object of ids are in the users array from db...

Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$in` it's can do the trick :

```
 User.find({userId: { $in : ['id1','id2']} })
```

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array. To specify an $in expression